# php объединение и foreach массива

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

у меня есть массив

```
[CONTACTS] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [kind] => PH
                                    [text] => 992927777777
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [kind] => EM
                                    [text] => ABC@MAIL.RU                                        
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [kind] => CD
                                    [text] => X21                                       
                                )

                        )

                )
```

мне нужно объединить массивы и из этого массива выбрать значение [text]

результат массива должно быть таким

```
[CONTACTS] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 992927777777
                            [1] => ABC@MAIL.RU
                            [2] => X21
                        )

                )
```

я новичок не судите строго пожалуйста

Comment: Судить-то нечего. Есть попытки решить задачу или просто надо код скинуть?

Comment: код есть но я решил не добавить его потому что там нечего смотреть и он не понятен здесь, @u_mulder если скините код буду благодарен, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($contacts as $current_contact)
{
    $result[] = $current_contact['text'];
}
```

Это почти то, что вы описали. Отличаются только индексы, если ваш массив сам будет элементом другого массива.